# Django multiple aggregates with annotate()

Tags: django

I'm very confused about Django aggregates and would appreciate some explanation with examples. Here's what the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/aggregation/#combining-multiple-aggregations) say:

> Combining multiple aggregations with annotate() will yield the wrong
>   results because joins are used instead of subqueries:
>
> ```
> >>> Book.objects.first().authors.count()
> 2
> >>> Book.objects.first().chapters.count()
> 3
> >>> q = Book.objects.annotate(Count('authors'), Count('chapters'))
> >>> q[0].authors__count
> 6
> >>> q[0].chapters__count
> 6
> ```

First of all, I'm not able to understand the part "because joins are used instead of subqueries". Can someone explain in SQL terms why this produces the wrong result and how subqueries will solve the problem.

Anyway . . . so the learning I took away was never to use multiple aggregate functions with `annotate()`, but right in the following part, the docs provide this example:

> For example, to find the price range of books offered in each store,
>   you could use the annotation:
>
> ```
> >>> from django.db.models import Max, Min
> >>> Store.objects.annotate(min_price=Min('books__price'), max_price=Max('books__price'))
> ```

Why isn't multiple aggregates a problem now?

Comment: In the first example, you are doing the same aggregation (`Count`) over different fields (that are joined and, thus, combinations of those fields are counted). In the second one, you are doing different aggregations over the same field.

Comment: Nice. I didn't notice that it was the same field in the second example. I don't understand the subqueries part though; how could have subqueries made saved the day? I understand it's a SQL question, but you'd be doing me a big favor by answer it. :-)